# Как правильно указать путь к плагину?

Tags: java, android

[картинка http://radikal.ru/fp/7eb7b1b16b5c417a981136bf02eb2cb9](http://radikal.ru/fp/7eb7b1b16b5c417a981136bf02eb2cb9)
[картинка http://radikal.ru/fp/7eb7b1b16b5c417a981136bf02eb2cb9](http://radikal.ru/fp/7eb7b1b16b5c417a981136bf02eb2cb9)
Я в build grade вверху добавил строчку с путем к плагину

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

сделал грейд и мне показало ошибки как на фото.

```
http://radikal.ru/fp/7eb7b1b16b5c417a981136bf02eb2cb9
```

Я так понимаю, что путь не правильно указан. Как правильно указать путь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какой ещё путь? Вы просто библиотеку с этим плагином к градлу не подключили. Надо добавить вот это в корневой build.gradle, либо в том же build.gradle где вы используете плагин `com.google.gms.google-services` перед применением плагина:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

На всякий случай уточняю что `...` - это то что у вас уже есть в секции buildscript.

В общем надо сделать то что [описано в документации](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#add_the_google_services_plugin).

---

Ответ на комментарий.
Не надо путать dependencies проекта и dependencies в секции buildscript. Первое подключает зависимости которые нужны в коде, второе - те что используются билд скриптом градла.
В общем вот так у вас должно быть:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tlalim.masa.paksclient"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.10.3.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: я опять что то не так сделал. У меня было так    'http://ideone.com/fllepa', потом я добавил то что вы сказали и получилось так  'http://ideone.com/A2tx65' . И теперь показывает еще больше ошибок. Как сделать правильно?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko дополнил ответ правильным вариантом вашего билд скрипта.

Comment: Да я уже понял)) только добавил эту строчку в билд проекта, но теперь переделал как в примере (добавил код в билд app) а из билд проекта удалил, НО теперь показывает                                        Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.

Comment: я так понимаю, что ему не хватает файла google-services.json я его скачал и положил в корень проекта... Он получается его не видит?

Comment: А Вы уверены что положили его в корень модуля в котором подключаете плагин, а не в корень всего проекта?

Comment: аааа)) все разобрался. Это файл должен лежать не в корне на на уровне app